# Proving $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{1}{x-5}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

> Prove that
> $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{1}{x-5}=0$$

Could you please check if the proof is right?

Given $\epsilon>0$, we must find some $N<0$ for which $|\frac{1}{x-5}|<\epsilon$ whenever $x<N$.
Since
$|\frac{1}{x-5}|= \frac{1}{|x-5|}<\epsilon$, it follows that $\frac{1}{\epsilon}<|x-5|$. We have $x\to-\infty$, so we may assume $x<0$. Therefore $|x-5| = -(x-5)$, and hence $\frac{1}{\epsilon}<5-x$. So $x < 5 -\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Take $N = -\frac{1}{\epsilon} < 5 -\frac{1}{\epsilon}.\\~\\\ Proof. Let\ \epsilon>0\ be\ arbitrary.\ Setting\ N= -\frac{1}{\epsilon}<0\ if\ x<-\frac{1}{\epsilon}, then\ x<5-\frac{1}{\epsilon}.So\ \frac{1}{\epsilon}< 5-x.\\ Since\ 5-x=-(x-5)=|x-5|,\ it\ follows\ that\ \frac{1}{\epsilon}< |x-5|\ from\ which\ we\ have \frac{1}{|x-5|}<\epsilon.\ Hence\ |\frac{1}{x-5}|<\epsilon.$

Comment: If you want to have $|x-5|=-(x-5)$ then you would need $x-5<0$.

Comment: We have x→−∞, so we may assume $x<0$. This implies $x-5<0$.

Comment: Correct.  If $\epsilon > 0$ then $N = -\frac 1\epsilon < 0$ and if we take an $x < N < 0$ then $x- 5 < -5 < 0$ so $|x-5| = 5-x$.  And Darsen's objection is not necessary or relevant.  And if $x < N$ then $x < - \frac 1\epsilon$ then $0< \frac 1\epsilon < -x < 5-x =|x-5|$ and $\frac 1{|x-5|}< \epsilon$ and your proof follows without a hitch.

Comment: My *only* objection is that I'd say "Since *we want* $|\frac 1{x-5}| < \epsilon$ it *would follow* from $\frac 1{\epsilon} < |x-5|$ which we *can have* if...."  .... but as you put it all forward in the right direction when you wrote your *actual* proof (which followed perfectly in direct order) my objection isn't that important.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have $y=|5-x|$ and discuss $\lim\limits_{y\to \infty}\frac{1}{y}$

Comment: Thanks for checking @fleablood. I see what you mean and I'll  take it into account for future proofs.

Comment: I guess that's right @herb steinberg, but I had to use the definition of limit a negative infinity.